# Highcharts organization chart (org chart) with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, highcharts, orgchart

I am trying to implement Highcharts organization chart in a React Native application, but could not find a perfect tutorial to start with. I tried Highcharts React Native wrapper but its is throwing errors. It will be highly informative if someone could find a perfect tutorial with is compatible with latest react native and expo versions.

Comment: Hi @Durga Prasad, Currently `organization` chart is not supported with the official `highcharts-react-native` wrapper. The wrapper is being rebuilt so you should be able to add external modules like `organization` soon.

Comment: Thanks for the update ...are there any other plugins for drawing org chart on react-native application ?

Comment: Sorry but I do not know any. I can recommend you to wait fot the new official wrapper release.

Comment: Hey @DurgaPrasad, have you found any open source for react native to help with showing org chart?

Answer (score 1):

I was also running into errors but I managed to fix them in the react-native-highcharts library. It is because the library uses webview as a component from the core react native which has been depreciated.

[npmjs.com guide on highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highcharts)

after installing and implementing all as described in the guide, install one more package by running the following command

```
npm install --save react-native-webview
```

after this, go to node_modules>react-native-highcharts>react-native-highcharts.js

in here, on the very start, find the import statements and remove WebView import from 'react-native' and add the following line after that.

```
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';
```

and now, go to the render method, here on the WebView element, you shall find a prop named 'onLayout={this.reRenderWebView}' like this

```
return (
        <View style={this.props.style}>
            <WebView
                onLayout={this.reRenderWebView}
                style={styles.full}
                source={{ html: concatHTML, baseUrl: 'web/' }}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
                {...this.props}
            />
        </View>
```

Change it to

```
return (
        <View style={this.props.style}>
            <WebView
                onLayout={this.reRenderWebView.bind(this)}
                style={styles.full}
                source={{ html: concatHTML, baseUrl: 'web/' }}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
                {...this.props}
            />
        </View>
```

Now run your app again and see if you still hit any bugs. I hope it fixes your issue